# Weird perspective behaviour

Tags: c++, opengl, voxel

I am currently implementing a simple voxel based game.
I've got the chunk logic and drawing/updating "working". However, i am currently fighting with a weird problem.

My engine works by cutting up the world in chunks. These are 16 * 128 * 16 in volume - whenever there is a chunk update, the chunk iterates through the internal 3D-Array (which contains ints pertaining to the block ids in the chunk), and adds Blocks to the internal "to be drawed" list that directly neighbor a block of air. These blocks are then uploaded into the VBO and drawn later on.

A block is 1x1x1 in dimension (ergo, `glm::vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)`), and their vertices are dependent on an offset. Ergo, the block the furthest away from the chunks origin (`mBlocks[15][127][15]`) would add the offset `glm::vec4(15.0f, 127.0f, 15.0f, 1.0f)` plus the block 1x1x1 geometry to the chunks VBO.

Again, i've got this part working no problem.
I also do have a camera class, that has methods for moving the camera (`moveBy`, which moves the camera position by  delta and optionally also the target point; `moveTo` which directly sets the camera position), setting the target center point etc.

When the chunk `draw()` method is called, it fetches the current ViewProjection matrix from the current camera as follows:

```
glm::mat4 vp = cam->getVPMatrix();
glm::mat4 mvp = vp * mTransformation;
```

The `Camera::getVPMatrix()` method is defined as follows:

```
glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(mPosition), glm::vec3(mTarget), 
glm::vec3(mUp));
glm::mat4 per = glm::perspective(30.0f, 1280.0f/720.0f, 0.0f, 1000.0f);
return per * view;
```

When running the program, i does draw something - the blocks themselves draw just fine, a plane white, and the formation is correct aswell. However - it would appear *everything* is upside down. The blocks are supposed to be stacked on top of each other, but stack downwards instead. Moving the camera right and left (i.e., increasing position by +x and -x) works fine, but moving the position in +y or -y direction has the exact opposite effect.

I suspect the problem lies with my ViewProjection matrix, but i just cant wrap my head around it.
This is what i see after adjusting the camera position a bit:
[image]

Again, the blocks should stack up-, not downwards.

Comment: In OpenGL the Y-axis, as in math, points upwards by default. Besides there is no enough relevant code in your question to conclude what's your problem.

Comment: @ybungalobill The project is a little too big to include in the question - what code do you think may be relevant? Also im aware of how the axis works - increasing the camera position in +y direction should move everything down, not up as it is currently doing. And everything is literally upside down.